# Use Custom Route with Google Maps or Apple Maps (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-maps, routes, mapkit

I am working on a project that involves computing a custom route from a particular origin position to a destination on a map. Ideally, this application should be able to give live walking/driving directions for this custom route, or it should able to send this route to the Google Maps or Apple Maps apps to handle the navigation.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the `Google Maps SDK` or with Apple's`MapKit` (or any other framework)? In theory, for short routes, this could be accomplished using the Google Maps `waypoints` feature, where points along the desired route are pre-specified, but the API is limited to 23 waypoints, which would become problematic quite quickly.

In essence, I want something like Google Maps, but with the route determined by my own algorithm rather than Google's.

Comment: I'm exactly looking for something like this. Have you got done this? Could you please help me out?. I'm spending more than a week for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom routes, you could use something like [Skobbler](https://developer.skobbler.com/) or [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/directions/).